# Is it possible to Speed control this AC Motor?

Tags: motor, ac

This is a 230V AC Motor. One Phase.

Is there a way to lower its speed?

[image: AC Fan]

I have tested using fan capacitors which didn’t work.

I tried a triac phase cutting settup, but it seems dirty, noisy (humm) and it seems the fan doesn’t like it.

The cleanest way seems to be a frequency adjustment. But of course its expensive.

Right now i am thinking of converting ac to dc, and then using 2 tyristors to create ac with varying frequency.

Comment: With variable frequency controller

Comment: Question should be closed - lack of research.

Comment: There are numerous very similar questions here. Reducing voltage is simple and relatively inexpensive, but more likely to be problematic. The cost of a VFD would make buying a new fan with built-in speed control very attractive. I will vote to close the question.

Comment: My research so far included using fan capacitors in line. It made no difference.   I also used a phase cutting mechanism with triac. Its very noisy (humm) and the motor didn’t like it.  I am now thinking of converting ac to dc, and then using 2 thyristors to convert that dc back to ac with varying frequency.

Comment: Converting ac to dc to ac with varying frequency is what a VFD does. That requires the voltage to vary in proportion to the frequency to avoid saturating the motor at low speed or losing torque at high speed. Even for a very small motor, you probably need to have ramped transitions from low to high and high to low frequency. With thyristors and a DC supply you need some kind of forced commutation.

Comment: Usually those "muffin fans" use simple Shaded Pole motors and reducing the voltage reduces the torque and thus the speed. Doing so with SCRs and Phase Angle firing should work fine, but I'm not sure what you mean by "phase cutting mechanism". When you use a traic instead of full inverse parallel SCRs, you can't control the firing of both sides of the device, because a traic only has one gate. It will work, but will be hard on the motor, which is probably the noise you were hearing. You should instead use an SSR that has true Phase Angle Control capability.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions:

1. Triac + controller (most of electric drills work that way)
2. Variable frequency drive
3. Big, ugly power resistor in series (placed in the air stream to keep it cool)